# How can I add some text after some sequence of text if this sequence matches certain criteria using Shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to add a statement just after the text matching the conditions mentioned in a shell script.

Below is my sample file (SQL file):

```
begin
AFFECTED_ROWS := 0;

UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE condition;

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);

MERGE INTO employees e
    USING hr_records h
    ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, address)
    VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);
end;
```

I will take this file and perform below transformation, once I see any of below Text in sequence

```
1: "UPDATE ... SET ...;"
2: "DELETE ... FROM ...;"
3: "INSERT ... INTO ...;"
4: "MERGE ... INTO ... [WHEN MATCHED THEN | WHEN NOT MATCHED] ... [UPDATE|INSERT|DELETE] ... ;"
```

I need to add 1 extra row just after the semicolon:

```
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
```

So that my new file will look similar to this:

```
begin
AFFECTED_ROWS := 0;

UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

MERGE INTO employees e
    USING hr_records h
    ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, address)
    VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

end;
```

I tried finding and implementing the approach in the scope of PLSQL but didn't find any generic way possible to get no of rows affected, so I thought
of text parsing but I don't know much about awk or sed.

For now what I was trying to do is:

```
sed '/Patterns Go Here/a   AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;' temp.sql
```

So pattern may have conditions mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see reason for the downvote, at least reason should be specified why it was downvoted, I have provided every information in a clear manner as per stack overflow.

Comment: This will unfortunately be very difficult if your SQL statements are split across multiple lines. If you can format the code to have one statement per line the task would be *much* simpler.

Comment: @l0b0 , Yes actually I tried with egrep when query is in 1 line and you are right that is pretty much easy , but unfortunately, i will be getting the raw file directly to which I was thinking to apply the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

If Perl is acceptable for you, it will be easy to do what you want because Perl is good at handling mult-line regular expressions. Then how about:

```
perl -e '
while (<>) {
    $text .= $_;
}
$add = "\nAFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;";

$text =~ s/^UPDATE[\s\S]+?SET[\s\S]+?;/$&$add/mg;
$text =~ s/^DELETE[\s\S]+?FROM[\s\S]+?;/$&$add/mg;
$text =~ s/^INSERT[\s\S]+?INTO[\s\S]+?;/$&$add/mg;
$text =~ s/^MERGE[\s\S]+?INTO[\s\S]+?(WHEN MATCHED THEN|WHEN NOT MATCHED)[\s\S]+?(UPDATE|INSERT|DELETE)[\s\S]+?;/$&$add/mg;

print $text;
' inputfile
```

**Explanations**

- First of all, it slurps all the lines into a variable `$text` including newline characters.
- We assign a variable `$add` to the additional line.
- Then we start to add the line to the pattern which matches any of the conditions.
- Perl's `s/pattern/replacement/` operator works to add the line.
- The `^` character is an anchor to match to the start of the line. Otherwise the pattern may match with the keywords within the `WHEN` conditions.
- The `[\s\S]` expression is an idiom to match all characters including newlines.
- `+?` specifies the shortest match.
- `$&` is a special variable to hold the string matched by the last pattern match. By using this variable, we can add the line following to the specified pattern.
- `mg` next to the rightmost slash is a option to tell Perl that we are handling multi-line text and to find multiple occurance of the pattern.

The script may look obfuscated if you are not familiar with Perl, but you can start with modifying the code and see what happens.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the approach, sure I will try to check.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl One liner

```
> export row='AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;'
> perl -ne 'BEGIN {$x=qx(cat ora_sql.txt);$x=~s/\b(UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT|MERGE)\b(.+?);/$&\n$ENV{row}/gms;print"$x"; exit }'
begin
AFFECTED_ROWS := 0;

UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

MERGE INTO employees e
    USING hr_records h
    ON (e.id = h.emp_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.address = h.address
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, address)
    VALUES (h.emp_id, h.address);
AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
end;

>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must look for a way the ask a simple question.
I translated your requirements into "Add a line after each `;` except for the lines starting with `AFFECTED_ROWS` and `end`.

The solution will use `/^(AFFECTED_ROWS|end)/` for matching the two exceptions.
The exclamation mark tells, that `sed` shouldn't do the replacement when an exception is found.

```
sed -r '/^(AFFECTED_ROWS|end)/ !s/;/;\nAFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;/' temp.sql
```

When you are going to insert values with a `;`, the above solution will fail.
When the `;` to be matched is the last character on the line, the command will be

```
sed -r '/^(AFFECTED_ROWS|end)/ !s/;$/;\nAFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;/' temp.sql
```

Comment: what if there is a SELECT statement which ends with ; and doesn't affect any rows?..

Comment: Is it possible to reset the `sql%rowcount` to 0 ? In that case the easiest method mught be adding lines like `AFFECTED_ROWS := AFFECTED_ROWS + SQL%ROWCOUNT; SQL%ROWCOUNT := 0`.

Comment: When each sql statement is on one line, you can expand the exceptions with `..|end|SELECT)`. Getting them in one line can be done with `tr '\n' '\r' < temp.sql | sed -r 's/\r\r/\n/g;s\r//g'`, but I would prefer setting the `SQL%ROWCOUNT`  to 0.